# NiceScroll show/hide

Tags: jquery, hide, show, nicescroll

I'd like to hide/show `NiceScroll` based on the result of an `if` function.

In my `html` there are three sections which are scrolled from left to right one by one.

My script is as follows:

```
var section2 = $('#section2').offset().left; 
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollZpos = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (scrollZpos <= section2 ) {
        $("body").getNiceScroll().hide();
    }
    if (scrollZpos == section2 ) {
        $("body").niceScroll({touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#67a5df",horizrailenabled:false,cursoropacitymax:1,autohidemode:false,cursorwidth:10,cursorborder:0,cursorborderradius:0,cursorminheight:180});
    }
    else if(scrollZpos >= section2 ){
        $("body").getNiceScroll().hide();
    }
});
```

It hides when scrolling outside of section 2, but when scrolling back it doesn't reappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this answer on Github.

It's better to create `NiceScroll` during the `document` `ready` event.

```
$("body").getNiceScroll().show()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link and the relevant text from the answer you found on Github?

Comment: @wilbishardis thx for upvote, and here it is issue post on github https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/215